# presentViewController and viewDidAppear not getting called in iOS5.1/6

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewdidappear

I have a view controller B in a parent view controller A. Both views are showing the same time.

In view controller B, I'm trying to present a new view controller using the following method:

```
- (void) buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    MyViewcontroller *vc = [[MyViewcontroller alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The view controller appears correctly in iOS6 and I dismiss `MyViewController` by using the following method:

```
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But there is a difference between iOS 5.1 and iOS 6.

QN1: Upon dismissal, view controller A & B `viewDidAppear` are not invoked. Is it supposed to be triggered?

QN2: I can't get `MyViewController` to show up in iOS 5.1.1. unless I add view controller B  as a child container to A:

```
[self addChildViewController:vcB];
[self.view addSubview:vcB.view];
```

By adding the child controller, I can get `MyViewController` to show and view controller A&B viewDidAppear will be called when it gets dismissed. `viewDidAppear` also gets called when using iOS6.

I'm not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1 : `viewDidAppear` will not be called when you dismiss a modal view.

Answer 2 : if you are presenting "`MyViewController`" from "`View-controller B`" then View-controller B's view should be in view hierarchy.

From here you can get more information. [How to Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

Comment: For #2, I did a `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` and the view hierarchy looks sane to me. UIWindow -> UIView (view controller A) -> UIView (View controller B) -> UIButton. I'm not sure where to look at?

Comment: I should also mention that this was without `[self addChildViewController:vcB];`, where self = view controller A.